# How to add directives to generated elements in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, events, angular5, angular2-directives

I'm trying to find the best approach to adding some directives and events to a generated table element and it's children.

I am programmatically creating a table in typescript

```
document.createElement('table')
```

I then add `tHead` and so on...
On my `<tr>`'s I want a to add `(click)="doSomething()"` for obvious reasons.

Do I have to go with EventListeners or is there a different/better way? 
I'll also need to add an *ngIf to a few things as well. Not exactly sure how to go about that.

Thanks for any advice pointing me in any direction!

**EDIT**
sorry for my not very descriptive question. Below is my table creation function. It uses recursion. This is why I am not using markup. unless there is a simple way to do recursion with directives.

```
    buildTable(tableData: any, properties: string[], tableId: string, tableClass: string): HTMLTableElement {
    let table = document.createElement('table');

    // setting attribute and class if they are passed in
    if (tableId) {
      table.setAttribute('id', tableId);
    }

    if (tableClass) {
      table.classList.add(tableClass);
    }

    // create table header with reference
    let tHeader = table.createTHead();

    // Create the header row with reference
    let headerRow = tHeader.insertRow(0);
    headerRow.classList.add('table-header');

    // Fill header with data
    for (let x = 0; x < properties.length; x++) {
      let th = document.createElement('th');
      th.innerHTML = properties[x];
      headerRow.appendChild(th);
    }

    // create table body with reference
    let tBody = table.createTBody();

    // dictionary for properties with nested data
    let subData: { [key: string]: any; };

    for (let x = 0; x < tableData.length; x++) {
      subData = {}; // clear nested data

      let row = tBody.insertRow();
      row.classList.add('table-row');

      let rowData = tableData[x];

      properties.forEach(prop => {
        let cell = row.insertCell();

        // Does this property have nested data?
        if (Array.isArray(rowData[prop])) {
          cell.innerHTML = prop;
          subData[prop] = rowData[prop];

          // build the sub table row, cell, and child table
          Object.keys(subData).forEach(key => {
            // sub table row
            let subRow = tBody.insertRow();
            subRow.classList.add('sub-content');

            // sub row that holds the table
            let subCell = subRow.insertCell();
            subCell.setAttribute('colspan', properties.length.toString());
            subCell.appendChild(this.buildTable(subData[key], Object.keys(subData[key][0]), null, 'sub-table'));
          });
        }
        else {
          cell.innerHTML = rowData[prop];
        }
      });
    }

    return table;
  }
```

This creates the table as intended. I now need to add events for showing/hiding the sub tables and clicking on rows to select the data to be edited/deleted/whatever. This would normally be a `(click)="doSomething()"`

Answer (score 0):

Easy way using simple ***ngIf** directive with combining data model:

```
   class TableData {
  isVisible: boolean = false;
  rows: Item[] = [];
  columns: Item[] = [];

  constructor(rows?: number, cols?: number) {
    if (rows) {
      for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        this.addRow(i.toString());
      }
    }

    if (cols) {
      for (let i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        this.addCol(i.toString());
      }
    }
  }

  addRow(rowTitle: string) {
    let row: Item = {
      id: this.rows.length,
      title: rowTitle
    }

    this.rows.push(row);
  }

  addCol(colTitle: string) {
    let col: Item = {
      id: this.columns.length,
      title: colTitle
    }

    this.columns.push(col);
  }
}
```

Template:

```
   <table *ngIf="tableView.isVisible" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of tableView.columns">
                {{col.title}}
            </td>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of tableView.rows" (click)="doSomething(row)">
            <td *ngFor="let col of tableView.columns">
                Cell
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Code example(Updated)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-generate-table)

Comment: a little addition to that: it is always a bad idea to do direct DOM manipulation in Angular. These changes may disappear at any time, when Angular triggers template update.

Comment: I edited my question to be a bit more descriptive. Hope it helps.